# How to find an average of N number of x values in the draw function

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

I'm using open frameworks and opencv to track blobs on a webcam. I'm getting the x value of the blob centroid and tracking it. The problem is, it jumps around allot, I'm wondering if there is a better way to compute the average position over a certain number of frames and use that number it's all being computed in the draw() function.

```
void testApp::draw(){
 ofVec2f centroid = contourFinder.blobs[0].centroid;
 int width = ofGetWidth();
 float pct = (float)centroid.x / (float)width;
 float totFrame = fingerMovie.getTotalNumFrames ();
 float gotFrame = totFrame * pct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a loop for N frames, sum all coordinates you get, then divide by N.

I am not experienced with ofx but there must be a function to get next frame.

After loop ends, move camera to the average coordinate and re-initialize the loop.